# calling many table in one query based on week

Tags: sql, sql-server

if there are multiple tables with the same contents like this:

table one:

| CustomerID | CustTrans | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C003 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C004 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-08 | 37 |
| C001 | 2022-09-05 | 37 |
| C002 | 2022-09-11 | 38 |
| C002 | 2022-09-23 | 39 |
| C004 | 2022-09-19 | 39 |
| C001 | 2022-09-18 | 39 |
| C003 | 2022-09-26 | 40 |
| C005 | 2022-09-17 | 38 |
| C006 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |
| C001 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |

table 2:

| CustomerID | CustTrans | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C003 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C004 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-08 | 37 |
| C001 | 2022-09-05 | 37 |
| C002 | 2022-09-11 | 38 |
| C002 | 2022-09-23 | 39 |
| C004 | 2022-09-19 | 39 |
| C001 | 2022-09-18 | 39 |
| C003 | 2022-09-26 | 40 |
| C005 | 2022-09-17 | 38 |
| C006 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |
| C001 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |

table 3

| CustomerID | CustTrans | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C003 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C004 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-08 | 37 |
| C001 | 2022-09-05 | 37 |
| C002 | 2022-09-11 | 38 |
| C002 | 2022-09-23 | 39 |
| C004 | 2022-09-19 | 39 |
| C001 | 2022-09-18 | 39 |
| C003 | 2022-09-26 | 40 |
| C005 | 2022-09-17 | 38 |
| C006 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |
| C001 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |

it's possible to make many table in just single table?

this is my query

```
CREATE DATABASE manydata;
CREATE TABLE trydata1
(
    CustomerID CHAR(7) not null,
    CustTrans date,
    CustSales int,
)
insert into trydata1(CustomerID,CustSales,CustTrans)
    values('C001',34,'2022-09-03'),('C002',23,'2022-09-02'),('C003',132,'2022-09-03'),
    ('C004',95,'2022-09-02'),('C002',68,'2022-09-08'),('C001',54,'2022-09-05'),
    ('C002',34,'2022-09-11'),('C002',98,'2022-09-23'),('C004',34,'2022-09-19'),
    ('C001',30,'2022-09-18'),('C003',34,'2022-09-26'),('C005',34,'2022-09-17'),
    ('C006',34,'2022-09-25'),('C001',34,'2022-09-25');
CREATE TABLE trydata2
(
    CustomerID CHAR(7) not null,
    CustTrans date,
    CustSales int,
)
insert into trydata2(CustomerID,CustSales,CustTrans)
    values('C001',34,'2022-09-03'),('C002',23,'2022-09-02'),('C003',132,'2022-09-03'),
    ('C004',95,'2022-09-02'),('C002',68,'2022-09-08'),('C001',54,'2022-09-05'),
    ('C002',34,'2022-09-11'),('C002',98,'2022-09-23'),('C004',34,'2022-09-19'),
    ('C001',30,'2022-09-18'),('C003',34,'2022-09-26'),('C005',34,'2022-09-17'),
    ('C006',34,'2022-09-25'),('C001',34,'2022-09-25');
CREATE TABLE trydata3
(
    CustomerID CHAR(7) not null,
    CustTrans date,
    CustSales int,
)
insert into trydata3(CustomerID,CustSales,CustTrans)
    values('C001',34,'2022-09-03'),('C002',23,'2022-09-02'),('C003',132,'2022-09-03'),
    ('C004',95,'2022-09-02'),('C002',68,'2022-09-08'),('C001',54,'2022-09-05'),
    ('C002',34,'2022-09-11'),('C002',98,'2022-09-23'),('C004',34,'2022-09-19'),
    ('C001',30,'2022-09-18'),('C003',34,'2022-09-26'),('C005',34,'2022-09-17'),
    ('C006',34,'2022-09-25'),('C001',34,'2022-09-25');
```

Comment: Have you tried with `UNION ALL`/`UNION`?

Comment: Why do you have several tables instead of just one?

Comment: because ive excel data and there's so many data until they have many sheet. if i import data excel in sql, it will make have many table isnt it?

Comment: because ive excel data and there's so many data until they have many sheet. if i import data excel in sql, it will make have many table isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

```
select *
from
(
  select * from table1
  union all
  select * from table2
  union all
  select * from table3
) t
where ...;
```

According to your sample data, this gets you duplicates, as some entries exist in more than one table. If you want to remove the duplicates, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

Comment: is it possible to create a new table with a new name?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS SELECT ...`

Comment: why i cant do this query? CREATE TABLE manydats AS SELECT *
from
(
  select * from trydata1
  union 
  select * from trydata2
  union
  select * from trydata3
) t

Comment: Maybe SQL Server des not support the standard `CREATE TABLE ... AS`. I know it supports the following propriatary syntax, though: `SELECT * INTO manydats FROM (...) t;`.